# Python: Cannot find object with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Can somebody please help me identify the Login/email, password, and LOG IN elements on this site?
https://lo12poznan.mobidziennik.pl/

I tried using multiple methods but my code couldn't detect them.
I just need the element identification...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to simulate an incorrect login using this script below - if you provide the correct login and password, I think this would work

Script as been written using `selenium==4.0.0b4` [ install it using `pip install selenium==4.0.0b4`]

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


svc=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=svc)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://lo12poznan.mobidziennik.pl/dziennik/")

time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.ID,'login').send_keys('warsaw@polska.pl')
driver.find_element(By.ID,'haslo').send_keys('MyCryptic@PAASWORD098')

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[type='submit']").click()
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

With XPath style the locators are:
login input field

```
//input[@id='login']
```

password input field

```
//input[@id='haslo']
```

submit button

```
//input[@type='submit']
```

You can use other unique combinations there as well.
And you can use other approaches i.e. by css selector.
Don't forget adding some wait / delay before accessing the elements to let the page loaded before accessing elements there.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

Login/e-mail     `[id="login"]`

password     `[id="haslo"]`

submit     `.btn.btn-block`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `find_element_by_id`

id for user name is `login`

id for password is `haslo`

and for submit button, use find_by_css_selector :-

```
input[class*='btn-lg']
```

Remember, xpath usages is not prefer in automation if we happen to find ids. or css.